# Is it possible to make overflowed image part invisible in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am working with images and faced an issue. My container can expand depending on the phone size and the picture that I am putting inside overflows in some cases. I want to make invisible the parts which are overflowed. Is it possible?

Comment: Share your code snippet

Comment: you may give it double Height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; for Container Height and  for width  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; then use this for container height and width for your image